# Pentaho Data Integration - MySQL Database connect with SSH

Tags: mysql, jdbc, pentaho

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database with Pentaho Data Integration (JDBC Driver).
Therefore I need to build up a SSH connection.

Is it possible to do this inside/with the tool?

**Guess I solved it:**

I just had to build up a SSH Port Forwarding:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 remote.url
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this that I know of in PDI. But you wouldn't really want to. I would take the approach of configuring your MySQL client to use an encrypted connection, and then connect your JDBC driver to that.

Sorry, I don't do MySQL, so I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

Brian